# On direct sum and direct product of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, universal-property

I understood the definitions of direct sums and direct products of groups (rings, modules, etc). The definitions of them can be given in terms of universal properties - certain commutative diagram in which arrows are in opposite direction (as compared from one to other).

However, I didn't get any idea how to arrive at the universal property of direct sum and product. I mean, given the two definitions of direct sum/product - set theoretic description and universal property - I understood their equivalence. But, what is intuition for obtaining universal property from set theoretic description/definition.

Most of the books put these two definitions, show their equivalence, but no one give intuitive idea for obtaining universal property.

**Edit [Added OP's comment]:** To be more precise, suppose on one page, I wrote definitions of the direct sum and product in terms of set theory, and on another page, I wrote definitions in terms of universal property, then how can I solve the problem: which definition on page 1 is equivalent to exactly one definition on page 2?

Comment: Usually the purpose of extracting a universal property is so we can generalize a useful concept to the categorical level, involving only morphisms. Something phrased this way can then be applied to other categories and behave in a similar way.

Comment: @MattSamuel I think the question is not about the motivation for finding universal properties in general, but about *how* to find them, or the intuition behind the definition of *each particular* universal property — in this case, how do we intuit the universal property of direct products?

Comment: @Vinay: yes. To be more precise, suppose on one page, I wrote definitions of direct sum and product in terms of set theory, and another pager, I wrote definitions in terms of universal property, then how can I solve the problem: which definition on page 1 is equivalent to exactly one definition in page 2?